# How to write multiple rows with unique column in django model field

Tags: python, django

I have a django model with the following presentation in mysql:

```
id    project_id    X    Y
```

where the model called `ProjectModel`, and here it is:

```
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=False)
    X = models.TextField(null=True)
    Y = models.TextField(null=True)
```

and this is my code:

```
projects = Project.objects.all()

for project in projects:
   model = ProjectModel()
   all_dict = extract_dict(project)
   # its like all_dict = {'item1':{'X': 221, 'Y': 'NewYork'}, 'item2':{'X':2.3, 'Y':'Milan'}, ...}
   for k, value in all_dict.items():
       model.project_id = project.id
       model.X = value['X']
       model.Y = value['Y']
       model.save()
```

I expect something like this out put:

```
id    project_id    X    Y
 1     21           221  NewYork
 2     21           2.3  Milan
 3     23           65   Berlin
 4     24           38   Amsterdam
 ....
```

I want to write every single item with even equal project_id in one row and then aggregate them using groupby. but I get error like:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '21' for key
> 'project_id_UNIQUE'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is very simple. You are using a ForeignKey for the link, but you are not linking the models correctly

```
projects = Project.objects.all()

for project in projects:
    model = ProjectModel()
    all_dict = extract_dict(project)
    
    for k, value in all_dict.items():
        model.project = project
        model.X = value['X']
        model.Y = value['Y']
        model.save()
```

Thus, you will link the project and projectmodel models using a foreignKey, while in the database the link will be traced by the id project. I advise you to read the django foreignkey documentation again

models.py

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    field_one = models.IntegerField() #idk what you want to save as x and y
    field_two = models.IntegerField() #idk what you want to save as x and y
    current_model = models.ForeignKey(to=ProjectModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As a result:

```py
projects = Project.objects.all()

for project in projects:
    model = ProjectModel()
    all_dict = extract_dict(project)

    for k, value in all_dict.items():
        model.project = project
        test = TestModel(field_one=value['X'], 
                         field_two=value['Y'],
                         current_model= model)
        model.save()
        test.save()
```

Comment: Thanks. But it just saves the last ket, value of all_dict in one row. So if my dictionary has multiple items just saves the latest items! Do you know why?

Comment: Can you describe your main idea of the model creation? I think that there is the problem with structure of models. now you are trying to override the field every time you loop. If you want to add a lot of values ​​to a field, you might want to reconsider your database architecture. Perhaps it is worth making a separate model for these values ​​and making a foreignKey field for each new model.

Comment: Yes, what I am actually thinking of, is creating separate models, however don't know how to make a connection between them.

Comment: This is my Structure, each project has a dictionary with keys and values which are lists. In the defined model, I am trying to add to each field, `id, project_id, first_key, its_values..`, the next field  `id, project_id, second_key, its_values...` Project_id in some lines could be equal as dictionary can have multiple item

Comment: it seems to me that it will be enough to store pointers to the next and previous project. so you will improve the amount of memory used and the structure will be logically linked in the database. I think there are many solutions with pointers, I suggest you google it. There is no need to keep the entire list for each of the projects as it seems to me

Comment: In general, in your case, it is better to create a separate model that will store the project_id as a field and store the foreignkey to the model with which you want to associate the project_id

Comment: Thanks. May I ask you to add your suggestion as an example to your answer?

Comment: Yeah, no problem

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added your new model, but I get this error: `ValueError: Field 'field_one' expected a number but got 'project'.`

Comment: Thanks, could fix this error by replacing X, Y fields in `ProjectModel` with those `field_one` and `field_two` in your `TestModel`